# Ext.StoreMgr versus Ext.StoreManager?

Tags: extjs

In ExtJs, what is the difference between Ext.StoreMgr and Ext.StoreManager?

I see both in the code I am working on and am worried we may have mixed versions of ExtJs or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are the same.

you can see in [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.StoreManager) `Ext.data.StoreManager` has 3 alternate names:

> **ALTERNATE NAMES:**
>   Ext.StoreManager
>   Ext.StoreMgr
>   Ext.data.StoreMgr